# Getting "App not found" from Trello Authentication

Tags: php, api, authentication, trello

I'm trying to call the Authentication part of the Trello API in order to get a user token.

I'm using this URL:
    https://trello.com/1/authorize?callback_method=postMessage&return_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftrello%2Findex.php&expiration=never&name=SB-Trello&response_type=token&key=[my api key]

But the response I'm getting is always "App not found"

Is there restrictions in what you can send in the "name" parameter or why am I getting this response?

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Closing this. As usual after asking something on SO, I find the answer myself just minutes after. After retyping the key it worked fine.

Comment: what was the answer?