# Trello API OAuth can't find my app

Tags: c#, api, oauth, console-application, trello

I'm using Trello's Developer API's implementation of OAuth to post stuff to a list.

I've successfully made a request and got my `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` back from https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken

But when I call https://trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken, passing the `oauth_token` that I've just received, I get a response of 'App not found'.

Can anyone help?

---

**EDIT:** Here's what I'm getting back from https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken

```
oauth_token=8d0e43fd0cc67726567d49ae5e818852&oauth_token_secret=[secret]
```

And here's the Authorization header I'm sending (escaped in C#)

```
"OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_nonce=\"8335006\", oauth_timestamp=\"1414663625\", oauth_consumer_key=\"9612eaca23c7bdd3eca60dc8c2a8159c\", oauth_signature=\"M6sLyyfHGYXOtQnLJexDx96kbFo=\", oauth_token=\"8d0e43fd0cc67726567d49ae5e818852\""
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this an error on Trello's end?

---

**EDIT:** I'm using RestSharp to call the Trello API, as below:

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://trello.com/");
var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("1/OAuthAuthorizeToken", Method.GET);
```

---

**EDIT:** Here's the complete RestSharp code:

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://trello.com/");
var request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("1/OAuthAuthorizeToken", Method.GET);
Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", client.BaseUrl, request.Resource));

string authHeader = GenerateAuthorizationHeader(uri);

//This is the output of GenerateAuthorizationHeader() 
//string authHeader = "OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_nonce=\"8335006\", oauth_timestamp=\"1414663625\", oauth_consumer_key=\"9612eaca23c7bdd3eca60dc8c2a8159c\", oauth_signature=\"M6sLyyfHGYXOtQnLJexDx96kbFo=\", oauth_token=\"8d0e43fd0cc67726567d49ae5e818852\"";

request.AddHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
```

The GenerateAuthorizationHeader method uses `OAuth.OAuthBase` to generate the TimeStamp and Signature for the OAuth request.

Comment: Could you please share which C# component you are using to communicate with the Trello api.

Comment: @LouisLewis I've just updated the question to show that I'm using RestSharp, and given the code that I'm using too.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for adding that, the picture is getting a little bit more clear now. There is one part in your code that I am not seeing, how are you attempting to use the authorization header with RestSharp? could you please share the "code block" that you pulled the snippet out of. Reason I am asking this, is because with RestSharp it has ways of assisting with authentication tokens. Seeing the "code block" will allow users to see the "whole" picture and provide you with help accordingly.

Comment: @LouisLewis I've just updated again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a trello problem...
this user, had the wrong key by the sounds of things.
are you 100% sure that the key is correct.
[Getting "App not found" from Trello Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112736/getting-app-not-found-from-trello-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the thing here is that OAuth is version 1.0 
When you get the token and token secret from the first call you have to make your user to visit https://trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken not you.

In your case you have to redirect your user to https://trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token=8d0e43fd0cc67726567d49ae5e818852&scope=read,write,account

He will get a page where he can Allow the access. Then you will get a verification code in the page after the authorization to continue with your process (GetAccessToken).

You can try this as a test, in a real application you have to specify a callback url and an application name in the OAuthAuthorizeToken call.